# Is there a GitHub hook to listen when a PR description changes?

Tags: github, github-api

Is there any event or way to get a notification pushed (webhook) when the description or title of a Pull Request changes?

I currently listed to `pull_request`event but it only fires when a PR is [“opened”, “closed”, “synchronize”, or “reopened”](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent).

I'm tracking some links/tags/word from the description of a PR and during the review of the PR, the author may change the description but I cant find a way to receive a notification when this is happening.

One way could be to be checking with the api for changes (polling) but I need some better way to receive get this (push).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## GitHub Pull Request Hook

###### Updated: the 26th of August 2021 26th of 2021

---

> Previously there was no such hook that could satisfy this answer, however 7 years have passed, and things have changed. The contemporary GitHub platform does offer a hook for listening to whether or not a Pull Request has been altered (aka "Edited").
>
> A very thorough, and well developed, [**`Pull Request Hook`**, or (***PR Hook***)](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request), now exists. As with all of the associated **"GitHub WebHooks"** , the [***PR-Hook*** uses a `Webhook payload object`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-object-common-properties) that is unique from all other `GitHub WebHooks`. The ***PR-Hook*** has special actions that can trigger code in response to a wide variety of events, however; for specifically to the altercation of a Pull Request's description, the **`edited`** action is what you will likely want to use.
>
> ---

##### [GitHub Official Documentation for `Pull Request Hooks`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request)

Comment: Luckily, this is outdated -- see my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible, since there is an action `edited`.

Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the thread! Save me a lot of time - it is indeed working as a charm